# Attendance month wise in aap.net c# or vb in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net, c#-3.0

I want to fetch data from db to grieview in below format.

I have data in db like that

```
Empcode   Date           Status
123.      01-01-2021.    P
123.      02-01-2021.    P
123.      03-01-2021.    P
.         .
.         .
123.      31-01-2021.    P
```

I want data like

```
Dates    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .....31
Empcode  p p p a a p p a p p .......p
```

Can you please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include these additions: 1) the code that you are having a problem with; and 2) the problem description,.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this does not really take much code. The trick is to reduce the formatting and markup.

so, drop a grid control into a form, say like this:

```
    <div style="width:60%;margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"></asp:GridView>

    </div>
```

So, now, on page load we have this code:

```
Public MyTable As New DataTable
Public dtStart, dtEnd As Date
Public DaysInMonth As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        CreateTable()
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub
```

Note how I did create the start/end vars at the form (class) level - might need those later!!!

so, our create table code is this:
(one month, but first column is the EmpID

```
Sub CreateTable()

    Dim dt As Date = Date.Today

    DaysInMonth = Date.DaysInMonth(Year(dt), Month(dt))
    dtStart = DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), 1)
    dtEnd = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, DaysInMonth - 1, dtStart)

    MyTable.Columns.Add("EmpID", GetType(Integer))
    For I = 1 To DaysInMonth
        MyTable.Columns.Add(I.ToString, GetType(String))
        MyTable.Columns(I.ToString).DefaultValue = "a"
    Next

End Sub
```

We also in above did set the default to "a" (absent) since any non data for the month of course should be "a".

So, now all we have to do is pull the query into a table, and then send it to the above table.

That code is thus this:

```
Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EmpID, ADate from tblAttend " &
                           "WHERE Adate  between @dtStart AND @dtEnd " &
                           "ORDER BY EmpID, ADate "

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStart
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtEnd", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtEnd

        Dim rstEdata As New DataTable
        rstEdata.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        ' now send data to our grid table
        Dim dPtr As Integer     ' day pointer
        Dim EmpID As Integer = 0
        Dim newRow As DataRow = Nothing

        For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstEdata.Rows
            If OneRow("EmpID") <> EmpID Then
                ' start of new employee
                If EmpID <> 0 Then
                    MyTable.Rows.Add(newRow)   ' add existing working row
                End If
                newRow = MyTable.NewRow     ' start a new row
                EmpID = OneRow("EmpID")
                newRow("EmpID") = EmpID
            End If

            dPtr = Day(OneRow("ADate"))
            newRow(dPtr) = "P"
        Next
        ' send last row
        MyTable.Rows.Add(newRow)

        ' send our data to the grid
        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Now above is a bit of code - but NOT really that much.

Assuming this data table:

[image]

And now our output looks like this:

[image]

so, next to none markup.

the key concept is to create a data table, then process the data to that table, and then VERY easy to display - we just bind/send the table to the gridview.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir it worked but one more thing is I don't wanr by default value as A
I have one more column where daystatus where daystatus are AB PRAB PR PRAP I WANT THIS VALUES AGAINST THAT CAN YOU PLEASE SUGGEST THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: ah, was not sure if you had data for "non" attend days. Just remove this one line to remove the default: MyTable.Columns(I.ToString).DefaultValue = "a"